# Efficient checksum of 8 × 16 bits integer vector using SSE4.1

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, checksum, micro-optimization

I work with color pixels of 8 components, each color component having 16 bits depth. Say, CMYK + 4 additional spot colors, but this is irrelevant: the important is that *every color can be represented* as an `array [0 .. 7] of word`.

Well, in the particular application we are speaking about it’s more convenient to work with 32-bits ‘surrogates’ instead, actually with *32 bits checksums* calculated from the color is a certain way. Of course I take care of the unlikely cases where 2 identical checksums still represent different colors. The idea is to meet such cases as rare as it’s possible, that is, the checksums should be as random as it’s possible and their computing has to be really fast. I’m allowed to use Intel/AMD `SIMD` up to `SSE 4.1`.

My idea is the following:

1. Adding different predefined constants (preferably prime numbers) to each component in order to get rid of null components,
2. Weighting these components by multiplying by different prime numbers,
3. Making the sum of the resulting doublewords.

Something like this:

```
movdqa xmm0, COLORPIXEL  // the color to get the checksum from
movdqa xmm1, WEIGHTCONST // e.g. (32749, 32647, 32573, 32503, 32719, 32633, 32569, 32497)
paddw xmm0, ADDCONST     // e.g. (32687, 32587, 32531, 32441, 32653, 32579, 32507, 32429)
pmaddwd xmm1, xmm0
phaddd xmm1, xmm1
phaddd xmm1, xmm1
movd eax, xmm1           // result in 32 bits register
```

This code seems to be enough good and reasonably fast, but better ideas are welcomed. I never worked before with checksums so there are high chances that a traditional solution e.g. different CRCs used in data transmission would be a better choice.

Note:

1. A color usually (but not mandatory) has just a few nonzero components, generally up to 3.
2. It’s quite rare that a nonzero spot component (that is, indexes of 4 or higher) to be paired with more than 1 other nonzero components.
3. Spot colors are by themselves much rare than CMYK colors (indexes of 0 to 3).
4. the value of 65535 (full tint) might be a little bit more frequent than other random values.

Comment: `phaddd` costs 2 shuffles + 1 `paddd` uop; never use it for efficient horizontal sums.  Can you just use x86 CRC32c instructions to do 2 qwords?  Especially if you want the result in an integer reg, not XMM.  I forget if those were introduced later than SSE4.1, maybe in the same CPUs as SSE4.2.  See [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](//stackoverflow.com/q/6996764) for efficient integer sums.

Comment: Are you sure you need the result back in EAX?  If you're going to transmit it, wouldn't you want to store it to a buffer in memory?  Also use a memory source operand for `pmaddwd` (unless you can hoist the load of the vector constant out of a loop).

Comment: @PeterCordes as this code is actually a part of a function I definitely need the result in `eax/rax`. Note that this function will be called very often (every time a new color is arrived), but impredictibile, so forget the parallel computing of the checksum for many colors in the same time.

Comment: Just to be sure, "SIMD up to SSE 4.1" means definitely no CRC32 instruction? And also no AES?

Comment: @PeterCordes Even the `SSE4.1` might be a rather high requirement for my customers but even so I can consider `SSE4.2` if the result really worth. But are you sure the `CRC32c` gives better (that is, more random) results than my weighted multiply?

Comment: @harold yes, at least Wikipedia says so. Another question whether I can assume or not that a desktop computer running RIP (Raster Image processor) software in 2019 should have at least `SSE4.2`.

Comment: SSE4.2 + CRC32C + AES would give you a baseline requirement of Intel Nehalem / AMD Bulldozer.  Those CPUs date back to 2008 / 2010 and are already obsolete themselves.  But Core 2 and K10 (AMD Phenom II) even slower, by a significant amount.  I'd guess you'd want to *tune* for Skylake / Ryzen, though, because that's what most computers will use.  (And Skylake tuning is not bad for Haswell; there's very little difference; just some uops can run on more ports, e.g. SIMD integer shifts, adds, and multiplies.)

Comment: Got convinced, guys. `SSE4.2` should be acceptable even for my Bangladeshi and Nigerian customers, so I have to go on `CRC32.`
    `crc32 rax, [rcx]`  
    `crc32 rax, [rcx + 8]`  
would be OK, wouldn’t it?

Comment: @PeterCordes AES is Westmere. So one after Nehalem.

Comment: @ZoltánBíró: I think so.  If you actually want a standard CRC3C there's a bitwise inverse in there somewhere, I think at the end.  But I don't think that adds anything to the strength of the integrity-check.  And of course you need to initialize RAX with some constant (perhaps just zero).